# How to make two JOINs on one table in SQL based on two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL query, which is returning a list of unique user ids combinations from `Chat` model in the format listed below.

My current SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, to_user_id, from_user_id) as sender,
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, from_user_id, to_user_id ) as target 
FROM chats AS pair
```

This returns two columns of valid user IDs:

```
sender | target 
1      | 2
10     | 12
3      | 4
5      | 4
```

I would like to return `first_name` and `last_name` from the `User` model alongside both the `sender` and `target` ids. I am not that familiar with SQL, so have been scratching my head over this for a while now.

What I am hoping to get back is something like:

```
sender | first_name | last_name | target | first_name | last_name | 
1      | Tom        | Jones     | 2      | John       | Smith 
10     | Chris      | Comb      | 12     | Sam        | Sloth
3      | Harry      | Houdini   | 4      | Jo         | Jones
5      | Will       | Wilson    | 4      | Jo         | Jones
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are the names stored?

Comment: A table called `users`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why wouldn't the "sender" be the `from_user_id`?

Comment: Because there isn't a separate conversation and message model, but I am querying this to essentially get conversations. I don't have enough to justify separate conversation and message models yet. Therefore, I want to return a deduped results based on the two column values: to_user_id and from_user_id. A  user can be both the to_user_id and from_user_id depending on whether they sent or received the message.

The below solution has sorted my issue though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. You may have to change the column names.

```
Select O.Sender, S.First_Name, S.Last_Name, O.Target, T.First_Name, T.LastName
From (
SELECT DISTINCT
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, to_user_id, from_user_id) as sender,
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, from_user_id, to_user_id ) as target 
FROM chats AS pair
) O
LEFT JOIN Users S ON O.Sender = S.UserID
LEFT JOIN Users T ON O.Target = T.UserID
```